# Save browsing history in IE8 in text format

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, history, browsing

I want to save browsing history for a certain day (Wednesday) from Internet Explorer 8 **in text format**.

I tried doing copy/paste from the history box in IE8, but it doesn't copy anything.

I was able to navigate to the hidden 'history' folder, but all I have is a bunch of folders and files with no apparent way to save it all in a text format.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please open powershell on your computer and paste in the following code (right klick > insert) and press Enter.

```
function get-iehistory {            
[CmdletBinding()]            
param ()            

$shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application            
$hist = $shell.NameSpace(34)            
$folder = $hist.Self            

$hist.Items() |             
foreach {            
 if ($_.IsFolder) {            
   $siteFolder = $_.GetFolder            
   $siteFolder.Items() |             
   foreach {            
     $site = $_            

     if ($site.IsFolder) {            
        $pageFolder  = $site.GetFolder            
        $pageFolder.Items() |             
        foreach {            
           $visit = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{            
               Site = $($site.Name)            
               URL = $($pageFolder.GetDetailsOf($_,0))            
               Date = $( $pageFolder.GetDetailsOf($_,2))            
           }            
           $visit            
        }            
     }            
   }            
 }            
}            
}

get-iehistory | export-csv $env:USERPROFILE\iehistory.csv -NoTypeInformation
invoke-item $env:USERPROFILE\iehistory.csv
```

The code exports the website name, url and date into a csv file that is saved in your profile path. The last line opens the file.

Comment: Amazing! Fabulous!!!